# rake operations with database using docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rake

With the following files I can start rails application successfully
except rake operations with database. When I run
docker exec -it www_web_1 bundle exec rake db:migrate
I saw that it tried to connect to localhost (web) and fail
instead of conntecing to database host (db)

Any ideas how to solve it?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.4.2
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/project
WORKDIR /var/www/project
COPY Gemfile /var/www/project/Gemfile
RUN bundle install
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin
COPY . /var/www/project
CMD ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
```

**docker-compose.yml file**

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: project
  web:    
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - PROJECT_DB_NAME=project
      - PROJECT_DB_USER=root
      - PROJECT_DB_PSWD=root
      - PROJECT_DB_HOST=db    
      - RACK_ENV=production
      - RAILS_ENV=production
volumes:
    mysql:
    web:
```

**config/database.yml**

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  database: <%= ENV["PROJECT_DB_NAME"] %>
  encoding: utf8
  username: <%= ENV["PROJECT_DB_USER"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["PROJECT_DB_PSWD"] %>
  host: <%= ENV["PROJECT_DB_HOST"] %>

development:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
```

Comment: What happens if you run `docker exec -it www_web_1 bundle exec rake db:migrate  PROJECT_DB_HOST=db`?

Comment: I have got "Aborted connection 4 to db: 'db' user: 'root' host: '172.18.0.3' (Got an error reading communcation packets)

where 172.18.0.3  is a web IP

Answer (score 0):

You have compose file.
you have to run compose command

```
$ docker-compose up --build                # run and build
$ docker-compose run web rake db:create    # database create
$ docker-compose run web rake db:migrate   # migreate
```

if you'd like more know docker-compose
visit https://github.com/x1wins/paper-flower/wiki/2.-Docker--compose-(Development-mode,-Standalone)